# Eclipse PDE product build succeeds but the executable is missing

Tags: p2, pde

Need help to build properly an Eclipse 4 pde product with a target in compatibility mode. The build runs properly, but executables are not included in the generated archives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the executable is missing you should make sure that your build is referencing the delta-pack for the target you are building. The target must contain the feature IU named **org.eclipse.equinox.executable** and it must be a non-platform specific target.